# How do I reference a in report calculated value on report footer?

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access Report Detail section, I have added a text box whose value is the sum of columns on the left:

```
Sum(Col1+ Col2+ Col3)
```

and I have named it `col4`

`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` are all actual fields in the table but `col4` is not. `col4` is just the name property of the text field.

This part is working perfectly fine. Now in the footer section I have added another text box and I have set the value of that column to:

`Sum(col4)`

So I want to sum all of the `col4` values.

However, when I open the report I get a prompt to enter the value of `col4`. What is weird is that no matter what number I enter as a value of `col4` it does the calculation properly and displays the correct result in  my `Sum(col4)` field. I would be all set if only it did not ask me to enter the value of `col4` on report open. Can someone give me some direction on how to fix this.

Comment: Access asks you to enter a value when it does not find a column with that name. You cannot sum() a text column. Without seeing the table definition and the query, it is almost impossible to give you further advice.

Comment: There is no column with that name. I added a text box and gave it that name. I thought I was able to reference that field within that report as if it was a table name field. And it seems like Access is fine with that as well. It's just that for some reason on report open event Access has some kind of thing that checks to see if everything referenced is a table field and shows that message. However during the process of populating data it realizes that it is referencing another field and does its job

Comment: Aggregate functions must reference table or query fields, not control names. Would have to repeat the complete col4 expression in the footer calc.

Comment: In a report or in a query, you can reference the textbox on an open form with `Forms!theForm!theTextBox`.